# Openai-gym : Setting is_slippery=False in FrozenLake-v0

Tags: openai-gym

In openai-gym, I want to make FrozenLake-v0 work as deterministic problem. So, I need to set variable is_slippery=False.

How can I set it to False while initializing the environment?

[Reference to variable in official code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L103)

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is to pass the is_slippery=False argument when creating the environment:

```
import gym

env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v0', is_slippery=False)
```